# global variable in python(using topological sort code as an example)

Tags: python

Here is my code of "topological order of graph" using DFS algorithm:

```
#dfs
def topological_sort(Graph):
    for v in Graph:
        if v not in visited:
            dfs(Graph,v)
    print(topo_order)

def dfs(Graph,start):
    global n
    visited.add(start)
    for w in Graph[start]:
        if w not in visited:
            dfs(Graph,w)
    topo_order[start]=n
    n-=1

visited=set()
n=0
topo_order={}

if __name__=='__main__':
    with open('topological_test.txt') as f:
        data=f.read()
    data=data.split('\n')
    data=[i.split() for i in data]        
    G={}
    for lst in data:
        G[lst[0]]=lst[1:]
    n=len(G)
    topological_sort(G)
```

I used 3 global variables `visited`,`n`,`top_order`.

The code above runs correctly given `topological_test.txt`:

```
s v w
v t
w t
t
```

If I delete `global n` in function `dfs`,there will be an error:

```
 UnboundLocalError: local variable 'n' referenced before assignment
```

Noticed that I didn't write `global visited` in function `topological_sort`,there isn't error prompt when running this program?

Why we need `global n` but not `global visited`?

Comment: Because you don't *reassign* `visited` in `dfs`, you merely *mutate* the object it references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `global` statement if you overwrite a global variable with a new value. But via `visited.add` you merely change something inside the already existing global variable.

If you wanted to change the set entirely on a global scale you would need `global`,
i.e.

```
def dfs(Graph,start):
    global n
    global visited
    visited = set() # creates a new empty set on global level
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n-=1
```

This is interpreted as `n = n - 1`.
This means it's looking to bind a new name to a value. This shadows the global `n` variable and since it's trying to assign itself to itself before it's been initially bound, it's raising the error you're seeing.

There is no assignment to a `visited` variable in your `dfs` function, therefore, `visited` is unambiguously referring to the global scope.